# What credentials need to be passed when accessing an SSRS report through URL?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2014

I know this is repeat question, but I have searched almost all the threads about this and have not found any solution to my problem. Some of threads show a solution like:

```
&dsu:DataSourceName=username&dsp:DataSourceName=password
```

But this doesn't work for me. What value should I give for `DataSourceName`?FolderName/SharedDataSourceName or only SharedDataSourceName? For `username` and `password` do I need to provide Windows username and password for where the report server is installed? I tried all possible combinations, but nothing has worked.

I am showing this report using Kendo Window & iFrame controls in an Angular SPA application. iFrame is being passing SSRS URL and showing report.

Firstly why does the `dsu:` & `dsp:` method not work for me? And if it's working but not secured as passing `username` and `password` then what other approaches are available for URL based reporting service?

Comment: Saying that something "doesn't work for me" isn't very useful for people who want to help you. Can you explain clearly what the current behaviour is when trying to view your report in a web browser (both directly at the SSRS URL and also through your iFrame if the behaviours are different)? Then people might be able to suggest some solutions. It's also a good idea to link to the other questions/answers you've already tried to use to solve your problem, or at least give details of the steps you've already taken.

Comment: will keep in mind your suggestion. (both directly at the SSRS URL and also through your iFrame) both the cases its prompt for User Name & Password. Currently working on intranet environment so if I add windows credential for reportserver system then it will open report directly without prompting User Name & pass word.

Answer (score 0):

In the RDL of the report and on your SSRS reports manager you should be able to set a DataSource and authentication type. If you have the RDL looking at a shared DataSource then put the DataSource in the same folder as the RDL and you can click 'Manage' on it and enter the credentials/authentication type you want